# Despligue de una aplicación java escritorio

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, servidor

no tengo mucha experiencia en java, estoy usando NetBeans para realizar una aplicación de escritorio y SQL Server; tengo una duda en cuanto a la comunicación de la aplicación java y la base de datos. Me explico mejor.
La base de datos se encuentra en otra computadora (en lan) que se usa como servidor, la aplicación en java que estoy desarrollando me genera un .jar, mi consulta es: ¿Necesito copiar el .jar en todas las computadoras que se usarán como cliente para guardar y consultar en la base datos? O es necesario hacer uso de los socket. La verdad no lo tengo claro o los sockets es un tema diferente.
Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Y si, imagínate que el jar es como el exe de una aplicación para windows.... Si el jar lo construyes con maven o gradle, debería incluir todas las dependencias así que es solo cuestión de poner el jar en los equipos y usar java para que se ejecute (en el terminal sería `java -jar el-jar.jar` mas los otros parámetros que se requiera).

Comment: Claro... podrías utilizar sockets "crudos" en una aplicación multicapas usando tu propio protocolo... pero eso sería reinventar la rueda aparte de que tiene muchísimas implicaciones de seguridad, concurrencia y un largo etc.

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida y la respuesta

Comment: Investiga JNLP. Para Java <=8 puedes usar WebStart, y para posteriores OpenWebStart.

Comment: Gracias por la información, voy a revisar el tema